# Get pixel information from canvas using ArrayBuffer

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, arraybuffer

I have a function to read pixel information from canvas. It looks like this:

```
function getPx (imageData, x, y) {

    var r = imageData.data[((y * (imageData.width * 4)) + (x * 4))],
        g = imageData.data[((y * (imageData.width * 4)) + (x * 4)) + 1],
        b = imageData.data[((y * (imageData.width * 4)) + (x * 4)) + 2],
        a = imageData.data[((y * (imageData.width * 4)) + (x * 4)) + 3];

    return {
        r: r,
        g: g,
        b: b,
        a: a,
        black: (r + g + b) / 3
    };

}
```

This works fine but is a bit slow. From what I understand from this article https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/12/faster-canvas-pixel-manipulation-with-typed-arrays/ there is a much faster way to read/write imageData from the canvas using something called ArrayBuffer. I can't unfortunately get this to work. So does anyone know how to do this?

**UPDATE**:

I have a canvas where I want to measure some points color or alpha value, so I don't do this an all pixels. My attempts so far looks like this:

```
function getPx (imageData, x, y) {

    var data32 = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer);
    var rv = data32[y * imageData.width + x];
    return rv;

}
```

This returns values and seems to be on the right way, however the values I get can look like this 4076863488 and 4244635648 and I'm not really sure how to turn them into the data I'm after.

Comment: The arrayBuffer is really faster when you iterate through the whole imageData. Not sure you'll get any improvements to just getting four indice in the image data. (Except if you're calling this function for all pixels !?oO Naah you probably don't.). But show us what you tried with the arrayBuffer so we can tell you what you did wrong. Otherwise, all we can do is rewrite the article you linked to, which is not really useful.

Comment: @Kaiido thanks, have a look again

Comment: Hmm don't do this. If you want to treat with 32bits buffer view, declare the arrayBuffer once, not at each getPx. Also, the value you've got needs to be converted to hex strings to be human readable (at least by me ;-) ). You can do so by using the `.toString(16)` method, then split each 2 chars and call back `parseInt(val, 16)` to go back to a base10 number. Beware the order is a,b,g,r on little endians. So I can tell your pixels were `0xfd000000` or `rgba(0,0,0,243)` and `0xfd000000` or `rgba(0,0,0,253)`. But there may be some way I don't know that let's us extract the exact value needed...

Comment: Anyway, once agan, I think the ArrayBuffer is good for setting the whole pixels of the ImageData. To get a single pixel, or if you don't need to perform an exact match, to stick with the UIntClampedArray you've got, is certailny easier and won't loose you significant perfs. Btw, I'm pretty sure you've got some other parts that needs to be optimized first.

Comment: @Kaiido Your right this is slower. But now I know. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Kaiido mentioned it's slower. But for anyone else who want to elaborate on this here's my final function.

```
function getPx (imageData, x, y) {

    var data32 = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer),
        val32 = data32[y * imageData.width + x],
        str32,
        a = 0,
        b = 0,
        g = 0,
        r = 0;

    if (val32 > 0) {
        str32 = val32.toString(16);
        a = parseInt(str32.substr(0, 2), 16);
        b = parseInt(str32.substr(2, 2), 16);
        g = parseInt(str32.substr(4, 2), 16);
        r = parseInt(str32.substr(6, 2), 16);
    }

    return {
        r: r,
        g: g,
        b: b,
        a: a,
        black: (r + g + b) / 3
    };

}
```

And also, it's better to put *data32 = new Uint32Array(imageData.data.buffer)* outside of the function if your calling this function many times with the same imageData.